# Detecting AngularJS onHashChange events externally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to listen for url modification events outside of an AngularJS application which uses the standard `ui-router`. Since Angular updates the location *hash*, I assume it would fire `onhashchange` events. However, in both latest Chrome/Firefox on Mac, it never does.

All I'm seeing (in Chrome) is the popstate event fired once for the initial load:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
  console.log('hashchange'); // Never fired
});
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
  console.log('popstate'); // Only fires on initial app load
});
```

Is there a different event I can listen for outside of the Angular code itself?

Comment: If you don't see the `hashchange` event, I wonder if they're using `history.pushState` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.pushState` should be triggering the `popstate` event

Comment: From MDN's docs on the popstate event: `Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a clicking on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript). And the event is only triggered when the user navigates between two history entries for the same document.`

Answer (score 1):

Based on evidence it seems to be using `pushState` and there's no events triggered for that method, so the only solution I've found is to override the pushState method and trigger a custom event:

```
// Custom pushState event
(function(history){
    var pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state){
      $(window).trigger('pushState');
      return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    };
})(window.history);

$(window).on('pushState', function(event){
  console.log('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: Note that in older browsers (old IE), they can't use `pushState`, so they do change the hash and work with the `hashchange` event